# List Group & User permissions for all files within a directory

Tags: permissions, batch-file

I have not written any code for this yet as I have no clue where to start (bit of searching returned nada, squat). I assume this is a batch script task but am open to other options.

Is this even possible?

Comment: take a look at CACLS - Display or modify Access Control Lists (ACLs) for files and folders.

Comment: Perfect thank you, will post my answer script when it's complete. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script I wrote for this which outputs all permissions for all files in the current directory of the **batch script file** to a text file:

```
for /r %%i in (*) do cacls "%%~i" >> "permissions.txt"
```

Now, **cacls** doesn't display very good output in terms of 'trawlability' and there are newer implementations out there (xcacls, icacls) but this worked for me on WinXP.

Thanks to [PA.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30447/pa) for the help (see comments on original question).